# Fsharp - Range evaluation

Tags: syntax, f#

Is there a way one can get a range in descending order?

Ex

```
[1..4]
```

evaluates to

```
> val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]
```

But

```
[4..1]
```

evaluates to

```
> val it : int list = []
```

Is there a different syntax to achive this without having to do a `List.Reverse` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to do:

```
[4..-1..1]
```

The -1 is the step